# Amazon EC2- user-data through the AWS console doesn't work

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, ec2-ami

From the Amazon EC2 console (or even if I do it through API tools on a box using a file), I paste:

```
#!/bin/bash -ex

# tell the world what we've done!
echo 'thisisthetoken' > /home/ec2-user/testuserdata
```

Into the user-data text box.  When the instance boots (the Amazon Linux AMI), the file is not in the directory.  Am I missing something so basic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in the original AMI; the current Amazon Linux AMI's work with the same user-data script.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that's newest AMI from Amazon. You can also test Ubuntu AMI from www.alestic.com.

/var/log/messages or /etc/log/syslog logs user-data executions.

Answer (score 0):

your AMI should support user-data (most alestic.com images do)